# Why cant I change the color of a JButton on OS X?

Tags: java, macos, colors, background, jbutton

I have this fragment of code:

```
JButton x = new JButton();
x.setSize(10, 10);
x.setOpaque(true);
x.setBackground(Color.black);
```

For some reason, the JButton's color doesn't change. After some googling and checking out some other questions on SO, it appears that this doesn't work on OS X for some reason. Is there a workaround or anything I can do?

Comment: This has to do with the LookAndFeel provided by OSX. Try the Metal LookAndFeel

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it worked. Pretty weird.